# Reduced relative clauses when a non-progressive verb is used (such as "have")

Tags: relative-clauses, reduced-relative-clauses

In subjective relative clauses, we can left out the relative pronoun and end its verb using "ing". For example:

> I can’t find my notebook that contains all my addresses.

> I can’t find my notebook containing all my addresses.

But what if the verb does not have a progressive form such as "have", "like", etc. For instance:

> I can’t find my notebook that **have** all my addresses.

Can we use this reduced form?

> > I can’t find my notebook **having** all my addresses.

Comment: I find the question a little confusing. *Have* and *like* **do** have progressive forms (present participles): *having* and *liking*. I guess you mean that they are not normally used in the present continuous if they describe states. Also, these nonfinite RCs with present participles sound wrong after *my* + noun. What sounds more normal is *I can't find that notebook [of mine] containing all the addresses*.

Comment: But to answer your question, no, you can't say *...that notebook having all my addresses*, for the same reason that you can't say *I'm having blonde hair*.

Comment: @legatrix thanks. Could you please explain about the following sentence and how the word "have" has been used? "I remember having an opinion on this debate".

Comment: Yes. In this case, the -ing form is used because *remember* requires it. It has nothing to do with the normal continuous tense forms. You can tell this because it means the same as "I remember the opinion I had"; you don't say "I remember the opinion I was having".